# What to do with optical wire after removing my antique Bose sound system

Tags: wiring, home-theater, audio

I have just removed a wired-in-the-wall old BOSE sound system.
I have these wires coming out of the wall that were connected to different components of the sound system.

- the wire on the left is an optical that goes to one of the Bose components. The tip is lighted red. Is it safe to leave it as in? If not what do I do to safely remove it.
- do I just cap off all the two speaker wires that come out of the wall?

[image]

Comment: Hey now, TOSlink was released in 1983. Let's not get to calling that "antique"!

Answer (score 5):

The fiber optic connector is TOSlink which is Plastic fiber optic lit by red LEDs, so it's perfectly safe to ignore, no hazard to it, though if it's lit, that implies that a component you presumably are no longer using is on the other end of it and should be turned  off...

If you are abandoning the speaker wire or leaving the speakers unused, there's no particular need to even "cap" the speaker wires. Just tuck them away if saving for possible future use. Cap them if you like or it makes you feel better.

Comment: @Ecneral, thank you very much. I don’t know why it is lit (red)as I have removed all components except the speakers (5x ) plus two ceiling speakers on a separate floor. Not sure whatelse to remove so that the tip is not lit (red). This particular wire is coming out of the wall.

Comment: Well, it's going to something that's powered and has an optical digital interface. The light is not hazardous, but whatever it's connected to is wasting power where it's hiding.

Comment: @Ecnerwal more like "coming from" than "going to" at this point. ;)

Comment: @Ecnerwal, is the other end of this wire a power plug? It could be that  as I see what seems to be an extension cord going in and coming out of the wall. Also the red light only turns on when I turn on the old TV.

Comment: There is no power, nothing conductive at all in a TOSlink cable. *"the red light only turns on when I turn on the old TV."* means the other end is plugged into the old TV.